# In refreshing data into div using jQuery it gives duplicate value

Tags: jquery

In my current project I am using jQuery calender plugin, you can see its demo

http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php.

Now, the problem is that whenever I am trying to refresh data by clicking on refresh button it give me duplicate values. Here I am giving you screenshot of my project before refreshing and after refreshing so, it can be useful for you.

[Before refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej1ds.png)

[After refreshing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gbBI.png)

In second image you can see the each data appear duplicate. Each time I click on refresh button it appear duplicate data, but on reload the entire page it gives me as first image.

I am using following code for refreshing. On refresh buttons click event

```
$("#showreflashbtn").click(function (e) {
    $("#gridcontainer").reload();
});
```

And the data come from the Database, I think the problem is that new data are come but the data which are already in browser and not clearing so it becomes overlaps.

Comment: Every time I click Refresh the calendar changes totally randomly. Sometimes there are duplicates, some things move to different days and times. Where does the event data come from? I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: I had give you the link for only reference to see, I had done some changes in that jQuery...
And ya data are coming from the database but clicking on refresh button is do not affecting in database...

Comment: That's why you have to put the code that you're having a problem with in the question. How are we supposed to know what you're doing wrong without seeing it? Also, it would help if you included a link to the plugin documentation.

Comment: As @Barmar says, we need to see **your** code, not just a link to the plugin you're using.

Comment: I had already given a link of plugin, but unfortunately I doesn't have any documentation for that....

Comment: @SagarUpadhyay, probably you need to clear existing stuff of your div before reloading it, for example **$("#gridcontainer").html("");**

Comment: Thanks guys, the problem has solved.
I was just making simple mistake that, I was refreshing data without removing old one so first I removed old data and re-append all the data.

Comment: @SagarUpadhyay Can you tell us how you accomplished that and then accept that as the answer so other people (like myself) can get this figured out too. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear your calendar data first before appending the new data. Try the following code before your reload:

```
$("#gridcontainer").empty();
```

You can find documentation for the wdCalendar plugin here: [Documentation](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/docs/)

Comment: I have the same problem as described. Just adding this call did not fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

In order to prevent duplications of events do the following:

In jquery.calendar.js file go to the `populate()` function.
In the ajax success function add the following line:

```
option.eventItems = new Array();
```

That will surely remove all the events and prevents duplicates.

The full code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: option.method, 
                url: option.url,
                data: param,
                dataType: "json",
                dataFilter: function(data, type) {
                    return data;
                },
                success: function(data) {//function(datastr) {                                  
                    option.eventItems = new Array(); // Without this line there will be duplicates

                    if (data != null && data.error != null) {
                        if (option.onRequestDataError) {
                            option.onRequestDataError(1, data);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        // Good response
                        data["start"] = parseDate(data["start"]);
                        data["end"] = parseDate(data["end"]);
                        $.each(data.events, function(index, value) { 
                            value[2] = parseDate(value[2]);
                            value[3] = parseDate(value[3]); 
                        });
                        responseData(data, data.start, data.end);
                        pushER(data.start, data.end);
                    }
                    if (option.onAfterRequestData && $.isFunction(option.onAfterRequestData)) {
                        option.onAfterRequestData(1);
                    }
                    option.isloading = false;
                },
                error: function(data) { 
                    try {                           
                        if (option.onRequestDataError) {
                            option.onRequestDataError(1, data);
                        } else {
                            alert(i18n.xgcalendar.get_data_exception);
                        }
                        if (option.onAfterRequestData && $.isFunction(option.onAfterRequestData)) {
                            option.onAfterRequestData(1);
                        }
                        option.isloading = false;
                    } catch (e) { }
                }
            });
```

I hope it'll help you

Comment: your answer helped me a lot. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue like what you described here. I found my problem is that I have to get my events data from database orderby the StartTime, which would help wdcalendar javascript code to clear events correctly. Hope it help you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#showreflashbtn").click(function(e){
                $("#gridcontainer").empty();
                $("#gridcontainer").reload();
                $('.filterevents').removeClass('fcurrent');

            });
```

try this its working for me